# How to \includepdf with filename from array?

Tags: pdfpages, arrayjob

i'm currently writing an application template. For the appendix i need to be able to include some pdf docs. The name of theese docs are store in an array. So i need to be able to includepdf where the filename comes from that array. But i can't get it working. Here is my mwe (actually my template is much more complex and has a cls file, but i think this does not cause the problem):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{arrayjob}
\usepackage{forloop}
\newarray\pdfdocs
\pdfdocs(1)={test1}
\pdfdocs(2)={test2}
\newcounter{numofpdfdocs}
\setcounter{numofpdfdocs}{2}
\newcounter{pdfdocsindex}
\begin{document}
    \forloop{pdfdocsindex}{1}{\not{\value{pdfdocsindex} > \value{numofpdfdocs}}}{%
        \includepdf[pages=-]{\pdfdocs(\value{pdfdocsindex})}%
    }%
\end{document}
```

Whats wrong? In my logfile it states:

```
! Incomplete iffalse; all text was ignored after line 17.
<inserted text> 
                fi 
<*> main.tex
                                       
! Emergency stop.
<*> main.tex
                                       
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's going wrong (and currently don't have the time to investigate), but how about using `expl3` for this job?

The following defines the macro `\placedocsfromlist` that loops over a comma separated list of file names and includes those. If you use `\placedocsfromlist*` the first token of the argument will be expanded (so you could use a list stored inside a macro):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \placedocsfromlist { s m }
  {
    \IfBooleanT {#1} { \exp_args:No }
    \copper_place_list:n {#2}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \copper_place_list:n #1
  { \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} { \includepdf [pages=-] {##1} } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\docslist{docA, docB, docC}

\begin{document}
\placedocsfromlist*\docslist

\placedocsfromlist{docA, docB, docC}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `expl3` you can easily apply a function on every item in a `clist`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N\pdfdocs
\let\myset\clist_set:Nn

\newcommand\myincludepdf[2][]{%
  \clist_map_inline:Nn\pdfdocs{\includepdf[#1]{##1}}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myset\pdfdocs{test-1, test-2}
\myincludepdf[pages=1-3, scale=.5]{\pdfdocs}

\end{document}
```